# jQuery hack fails in Opera, alternatives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, opera

I have a form which I want to use both as a report view and a form. Initially the text inputs (text and textarea) are styled to have no border / background. I also use the following jQuery code to make sure they will reject focus:

```
$('input[type="text"], textarea').focus(function() {
  $(this).blur();
});
```

This works in Firefox, but it doesn't in Opera (<del>and maybe other webkit browsers</del>). I don't want to use `disabled` property because then I cannot style the input to be unobtrusive (in the general sense). I can hide the input and display a span or div in its place where the state is `view` and then swap the visible-hidden property when state changes to `form`, in fact I'm doing this for selects, radio buttons, and checkboxes. But it'd be less work if I can get it work as is. Any suggestions?

Edit - Removed webkit tag, thank you Fylke.

Comment: What's `$this`? Do you mean `this` ?

Comment: @Pekka - Oh, yes that's a typo here, besides others ;). in the original code it is correct, I'll edit and correct, thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that Opera is not a webkit browser, maybe that's not what you are implying but it sure looks like it.

Comment: *"...it doesn't in Opera (and maybe other webkit browsers)..."* Opera isn't a WebKit browser. Safari and Chrome use WebKit, Opera uses its own rendering engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use [the "readonly" attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-readonly) instead of "disabled"? Setting "readonly" to `true` will not change the way the fields look (meaning that you can do that with CSS), but it prevents modification.

That said, this approach to re-using layout can be problematic when your field values take up more room than allocated on the layout.  When they're editable text fields, users generally understand that they can scroll the value around, but that becomes pretty weird when the fields don't look like fields.

Comment: Took the liberty of adding a link.

Comment: +1 Thank you! You'd be a life saver if that was what's on stack! Accept will follow shortly (after a test ;))

Comment: Thanks @TJ!! I was just looking for a good succinct description somewhere. (Does anybody but me still use the ancient blooberry.com HTML docs?)

Comment: For the time being this is very unlikely to happen and if it does it will be very rare. But I think I'd change it in favor of sibling spans and divs.